# Can I fopen with shared read write?

Tags: c, windows, file, fopen

Can I create a file in C 
that will be accessible at any time in user mode?

I mean like

```
    zwcreatefile(...shareread||sharewrite...)
```

Can I make it with fopen in user mode ?

I want my log file to be shared read write so when my program is running I can still open it and view the logs while my program still writing to there.

Comment: you can open file a file multiple times with `O_APPEND`. All writes will be at the end. This is using `open` not `fopen`

Comment: open is int __cdecl(const char* filename,int flags)

and where I get FILE handle?
I mean , can you provide a little example? I never heard about open :-O

Comment: Did you try using [`_fsopen()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f30b0db(VS.80).aspx)?

Comment: I trying it now , but something is strange going on here :(
I working with 2 files , in 1 file (lets call it file1) it does fprintf(); to it and seccond file is empty ...
I did all the same , but it is empty , I deleted the first file and deleted the function that writes to it , and still file2 is still empty . :((

Comment: Thanks you , I still have no idea how or why but I did it with _fsopen solution , It works fine thanks you :)

Comment: @user2533527: Go ahead and write an answer with the code you are using that makes it work, and accept it, so that it will help people in the future looking for answers to the same question.

Comment: Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in 4 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <share.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *FPlogHigh; 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    FPlogHigh = _fsopen("filename.txt", "a+",_SH_DENYWR);
    if (FPlogHigh)
    {
        fprintf(FPlogHigh,"\nHello log started\n");
        fclose(FPlogHigh);
    }
    ...
}
```

I opening and closing the file handle each time I want to write there. It allows me to access the log file from any other program.
I also can not change log in other program while this 1 is writing to log file
but as it closes FCLOSE(); I can edit 
a+ stands for append it writes to the end of the file each times it opens.

Comment: Beware, `_fsopen` is Windows-only.